# Basic phpmailer question

Tags: php, phpmailer, newsletter

I am using phpmailer to send my newsletter to my subscribers.

I set my headers as following:

```
$headers = "From: Sales - Blah Blah <sales@blahblah.com>";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
```

NOW, in the delivered email, for example in a gmail account, if you press the "show details" link, the following appears.

```
from    Sales - Blah Blah MIME-Version: 1.0 

sales@blahblah.com via ecbiz103.inmotionhosting.com 

to  blahblah@gmail.com

date    Wed, Aug 3, 2011 at 11:02 AM

subject sales !

***mailed-by    ecbiz103.inmotionhosting.com***
```

HERE IS THE QUESTION:

HOW CAN I MAKE IT ACTUALLY SEND THE EMAIL FROM THE ACTUAL EMAIL ACCOUNT, that is "sales@blahblah.com" and be able to see the outgoing emails on my "sent" tab?

I guess, when this happens, the last line mentioned in bold would say

```
"mailed by blahblah.com"
```

Regards, George

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: you cant.

All phpmailer does is connect to the mail server to send the mail. It does not link to your actual e-mail account in any way at all.

---

EDIT:

Also, you will not be able to remove the `ecbiz103.inmotionhosting.com` reference as that is the hostname of the server that is sending the mail. A mail server runs on one IP address, this IP has a hostname, in this case `ecbiz103.inmotionhosting.com`.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I thought, but then I realized that in some newsletter I receive, is says "mailed-by groupon.com". The example of groupon is totally random! So, I wanna achieve the same.. cause right now it says mailed by "the company that hosts the website"!

Comment: Well the company I'm hosted with use private hostnames so it does not display the actual company name. The only way to achieve this is to get your own VPS or dedicated server.

Answer (score 1):

PHPmailer as in http://phpmailer.worxware.com? Or do you mean PHP's built-in `mail()` function? It would appear you're using mail(), since you're building your own MIME message. Don't do that. It's too much main and unreliable. use PHPmailer (at the link mentioned earlier) or [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org) to do that sort of thing for you.

Either way, if you want the mails you send to show up in your account's "sent" folder, you'd have to send the emails via your own email account using blahblah.com's mail server. Another option would be to set a BCC: to silently copy yourself on each mail, and have a mail rule on your account to divert those mails to a folder.

Comment: "Either way, if you want the mails you send to show up in your account's "sent" folder, you'd have to send the emails via your own email account using blahblah.com's mail server". 

Can I do that automatically, using php for example, or I have to send each mail manually?? Cause remember, it is a newsletter, so I cannot send all emails at once cause all email accounts will be visible to all subscribers.

Comment: with just PHP's mail() function, no. PHPMailer and Swiftmailer can use any mail server you tell them to.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a newline after the first line of headers, specifically the `From` header.